# ちゃんとFooterの形にしたいです。

Tags: html, css

[コチラ](https://codepen.io/scanfcode/pen/MEZPNd) を見本にFooterを作成してみましたが、うまくいきません。
どこを調整すれば、きちんと反映されるのでしょうか？

**具体的にどのようにしたいのか**
まず、見本のように横いっぱいにFooterを広げたいです。
そして、見本でいうAboutのあたりにコピーライトを、見本のカテゴリーにはカテゴリーを配置したいです。カテゴリーは上から縦に並べます。色味に関しては#f2f2f2を基調としたいです。

```css
footer.site-footer
{
   background-color:#f2f2f2;
   padding:45px 0 20px;
   font-size:15px;
   line-height:24px;
   color:#807e7e;
}
footer.site-footer hr
{
  opacity:0.5
}
footer.site-footer hr.small
{
  margin:20px 0
}
footer.site-footer h6
{
  font-size:16px;
  color:#807e7e;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-top:5px;
  letter-spacing:2px
}
footer.site-footer a
{
  color:#807e7e;
}
footer.site-footer a:hover
{
  color:#3366cc;
  text-decoration:none;
}
ul.footer-links
{
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:0;
  list-style:none;
}
ul.footer-links li
{
  display:block
  list-style:none;
}

ul.footer-links a:active,.footer-links a:focus,.footer-links a:hover
{
  text-decoration:none;
}
ul.footer-links.inline li
{
  display:inline-block
}
footer.site-footer
{
  text-align:right
}
footer.site-footer
{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  margin-left:6px;
  margin-right:0;
  border-radius:100%;
  background-color:#33353d
}

li.footer-item{
list-style:none;
}

@media (max-width:991px)
{
  footer.site-footer [class^=col-]
  {
    margin-bottom:30px
  }
}
@media (max-width:767px)
{
  footer.site-footer
  {
    padding-bottom:0
  }
  footer.site-footer
  {
    text-align:center
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <p class="text-justify">© 2021 Copyright: <a class="text-reset fw-bold" href="#">XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <h6>Categories</h6>
          <ul class="footer-links">
              {% for item in footer.menu_items.all %}
                <li class="footer-item">
                    <a href="{{ item.link }}" class="footer-link text-reset" aria-current="page" {% if item.open_in_new_tab %} target="_blank"{% endif %}>{{ item.title }}</a>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
          <h6>Categories</h6>
          <ul class="footer-links">
              {% for item in footer.menu_items.all %}
                  <li class="footer-item">
                      <a href="{{ item.link }}" class="footer-link text-reset" aria-current="page" {% if item.open_in_new_tab %} target="_blank"{% endif %}>{{ item.title }}</a>
                  </li>
              {% endfor %}
          </ul>
      </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: 参考にしたCSSそのままではなくかなり改変されていますね。そうなると質問者様がどのように表示したいのかがわからないと回答が難しい印象です。ぜひ質問文を編集して、どういったことを実現したいのか追記してください

Comment: @keitaro_so さん　イメージ追記いたしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず第一として、参考にしているサイトはBootstrap jQuery fontawesome のライブラリを利用しているようです。まずはそれをきちんと記述するようにしましょう。

※コピーライト等も表示されていると思いますが、よくわからない丸い楕円が存在しています。
これは質問中に要件もなく、何をしたいのかよくわからないので、ご自身で調整をしてみてください。

```css
footer.site-footer
{
   background-color:#f2f2f2;
   padding:45px 0 20px;
   font-size:15px;
   line-height:24px;
   color:#807e7e;
}
footer.site-footer hr
{
  opacity:0.5
}
footer.site-footer hr.small
{
  margin:20px 0
}
footer.site-footer h6
{
  font-size:16px;
  color:#807e7e;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-top:5px;
  letter-spacing:2px
}
footer.site-footer a
{
  color:#807e7e;
}
footer.site-footer a:hover
{
  color:#3366cc;
  text-decoration:none;
}
ul.footer-links
{
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:0;
  list-style:none;
}
ul.footer-links li
{
  display:block
  list-style:none;
}

ul.footer-links a:active,.footer-links a:focus,.footer-links a:hover
{
  text-decoration:none;
}
ul.footer-links.inline li
{
  display:inline-block
}
footer.site-footer
{
  text-align:right
}
footer.site-footer
{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  margin-left:6px;
  margin-right:0;
  border-radius:100%;
  background-color:#33353d
}

li.footer-item{
list-style:none;
}

@media (max-width:991px)
{
  footer.site-footer [class^=col-]
  {
    margin-bottom:30px
  }
}
@media (max-width:767px)
{
  footer.site-footer
  {
    padding-bottom:0
  }
  footer.site-footer
  {
    text-align:center
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <p class="text-justify">© 2021 Copyright: <a class="text-reset fw-bold" href="#">XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <h6>Categories</h6>
          <ul class="footer-links">
              {% for item in footer.menu_items.all %}
                <li class="footer-item">
                    <a href="{{ item.link }}" class="footer-link text-reset" aria-current="page" {% if item.open_in_new_tab %} target="_blank"{% endif %}>{{ item.title }}</a>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
          <h6>Categories</h6>
          <ul class="footer-links">
              {% for item in footer.menu_items.all %}
                  <li class="footer-item">
                      <a href="{{ item.link }}" class="footer-link text-reset" aria-current="page" {% if item.open_in_new_tab %} target="_blank"{% endif %}>{{ item.title }}</a>
                  </li>
              {% endfor %}
          </ul>
      </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```